# Limitations with socket.io?

Tags: mobile, websocket, socket.io

I am planning to use socket.io inside a hybrid mobile application packaged for a mobile device. Are there any limitations that I might encounter with browser adoption or anything of that sort? Will this sort of a set up work with all mobile devices when packaged and distributed?

---

### Updated details

I am going to use it to write a chat application. If I do a basic chat application using socket.io and then package it using PhoneGap or Cordova/Ionic, would there be any issues with compatibility or can I expect all the features to work seamlessly?

Comment: This is a very broad question with no specifics around which someone could write an answer.  socket.io works just great in some mobile circumstances on some platforms.  It is not ideal in other situations.  A general answer when given no specifics could take hundreds of pages to document and is likely beyond what any single person here knows (lots of platforms, lots of situations, lots of different application needs). As such, this question is just "too broad" for stack overflow. If you describe a specific problem and a specific platform you are using, then maybe people could comment for that.

Comment: I am going to use it to write a chat application. If I do a basic chat application using socket.io and then package it using PhoneGap or Cordova/Ionic, would there be any issues with compatibility or can I expect all the features to work seamlessly?

Comment: That makes it a bit a more manageable question.  Are you just targeting iOS and Android?  Perhaps someone who knows those packagers can comment now.  One issue to do some research on would be what happens when your app is not the foreground app.  Does it still get messages appropriately without using the platform-specific push system?  Is it still friendly with battery life?  A socket.io server expects a regular heartbeat from the client to know that the client is still alive.  I'm not sure that works for long term client use.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the pointers. I am targeting mainly iOS and Android but all devices/OSes (Windows, Blackberry?) would be ideal.